# Does Yemen have the right under international law to close Bab El Mandeb strait?

Tags: international-law, israel, yemen, international-waters

As Yemen [warned](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/dec/13/yemen-houthis-red-sea-ship-israel-attack) ships in Red Sea to avoid Israel or face attack, I wonder if it has the right under international law to stop these ships from crossing the strait.

Is Yemen breaking an international law by doing this or is this within its right and sovereignty?

Comment: *Yemen Hourhis* warned, not *Yemen* - since Hourhis are not internationally recognized government, their declarations have nothing to do with the international law.

Comment: Please, clarify what you mean by "international law."  It's too vague as written.  Any specific treaty or set of treaties that you have in mind?

Comment: If a regime violates international laws and no one does anything to stop its illegal behavior, then anyone has the right to do anything to pressure the aggressor. Rules are for everyone.

Comment: I'm wondering if international treaties like these still matter. It seems in the years since 9/11 the world has gradually moved to shit and piss on things like that.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No.  As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bab-el-Mandeb#Significance_in_the_maritime_trade_route) puts it:

> Under the purview of the article 37 of the [United Nations Convention on the Law of the Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Convention_on_the_Law_of_the_Sea), the legal concept of [transit passage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transit_passage) applies to Bab el-Mandeb, although Eritrea (unlike the rest of coastal countries) is not a party to the convention.

Yemen [ratified the UNCLOS III treaty](https://www.un.org/Depts/los/reference_files/chronological_lists_of_ratifications.htm) in 1987.

Comment: Can you please quote the part that references Bab El Mandeb from the treaty?

Comment: @Mocas,  Kelvin already has cited the relevant section: Art 37 "This section applies to straits which are used for international navigation between one part of the high seas or an exclusive economic zone and another part of the high seas or an exclusive economic zone"  That the Bab el Mandreb strait satisfies these condition is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: but the current Houthi government did not ratify the UNCLOS III right...or did they?

Comment: @FaitoDayo Countries are bound by previous treaties even if they change of government. Any other way, there would be impossible to keep treaties as the governments change often. No matter who wins the next elections in, say, Italy, they will not have to ratify all current EU treaties (for example). So, there is no need for the Houthis to have ratified UNCLOS III for them to be bound by it, if they are acting as Yemen's government. A new government can withdraw from a treaty, but that is a different act.

Comment: @FaitoDayo and if the Houthis withdraw from UNCLOS, that does not mean that the rest of the world will just say "ok, as you wish." Most likely, the rest of the world will understand that the convention is still in place (as it has been approved by most of the world), and that sending naval assets to protect passage is ok. And that now, such naval assets are not bound by the limitations of UNCLOS and can do way more than "innocent passage".

Comment: Not to mention, by my understanding, the houthis arent recognised as the legitimate yemeni government

Comment: Countries are bound by previous treaties until they decide to ignore them—which sometimes happens before they even sign them.  But that isn't relevant to the particular case of this question.

Answer (score 26):

The quotes article attributes the threat of attack to *Yemen Houthis*, which are a rebel group, rather than the official government of Yemen:

> A senior official from Yemen’s Houthis has warned cargo ships in the Red Sea to avoid travelling towards Israel and the occupied territories, after the Iran-aligned group claimed an attack on a commercial tanker earlier in the day.

As Houthis do not represent *Yemen* under the international law, their declarations have no legal meaning. Any attack carried out by them is a criminal act by outlaws - since they exist and act outside of the international law.

Comment: Does international law determine which government is "official," or do Yemenis?

Comment: @JDoe one has to distinguish *official*, *legitimate*, and *de facto* governments. So yes, only the government recognized internationally can apply the international law. The fact that Houthis run the country (i.e., they are *de facto* government) doesn't mean that they are *legitimate* - i.e., have support of the population - they took power by force, not via elections.

Comment: Who says elections are the standard of legitimacy? Does that mean Saudi Arabia’s monarchy is illegitimate?

Comment: @JDoe [*equivocation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation): *legitimacy* is whether the government accepted by population. Sometimes the term is used interchangeably with *legality*, but in the context of my previous comment it should cause no ambiguity: Saudi government is internationally recognized, but it is difficult to say whether it has support of the majority of the Saudis.

Comment: So the “official” government is the one recognized by other countries, and explicitly not the one recognized by the people governed? What sense does it make to disparage the effective de facto government as a “rebel group”?

Comment: @JDoe neither international law nor internal support. Each country gets to decide which government they consider legitimate, and they do not need to agree with other countries.

Comment: @JDoe Houthis are de facto rebel group.

Comment: @JDoe From the point of view of _international_ law, the thing that matters is what the _international_ community thinks. Over time international and national opinions generally align as a matter of _real politik_ but it can take considerable time, and there are often wider political considerations that prevent _de facto_ realities from being recognised by particular states.

Comment: @JackAidley SJuan76 What international law are you talking about? Nobody has yet cited a single international law that should apply and overrule the will of the people of a country wrt their own government.

Comment: @JDoe the question is about the international freedom of navigation. The freedom of the people (which Houthis do not express) ends at the Yemen border.

Comment: @RogerV. You claimed "Houthis do not represent Yemen under the international law" - what law are you talking about? What international law dictates which government gets to govern a country?

Comment: The entire notion of "international law" is somewhat inconsistent with the notion of sovereignty.  And in practice, many nations choose to behave inconsistently with both notions.  And even in the "United" Nations, five countries have the ability to veto any resolution, even if voted for by 192 other nations.

Comment: @WGroleau the point is that Houthis are not a part of this system in any meaningful sense.

Comment: And my point is that they are not a part of a system that in itself is not very meaningful.

Comment: @WGroleau the question is about the system... In fact, this whole SE is about systems that are not very meaningful :D