# Arab League boycott of Israeli navigation beyond Suez and the straights of Tiran

Tags: israel, 2023-israel-hamas-war, yemen

In the past, as part of [the Arab League Boycott of Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_League_boycott_of_Israel), Egypt tried closing the Suez Channel and [the Straits of Tiran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straits_of_Tiran). The question was eventually settled in [the peace treaty between Israel and Egypt, which guaranteed to Israel the freedom of navigation in these zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli_passage_through_the_Suez_Canal_and_Straits_of_Tiran). However, in connection to the Yemen Houthis' action against the Israeli shipping, I wonder on what occasions (if ever) the Arab League members tried blocking Israeli shipping elsewhere - e.g., in [Bab-el-Mandeb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bab-el-Mandeb). Are there any agreements between Israel and/or US and the Arab League members that guarantee the freedom of shipping to Israel? Or is it guaranteed by default by the international law (in which case the past Egyptian blockades were violations?)

Related:
[*Does Yemen have the right under international law to close Bab El Mandeb strait?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/83647/38304)
[*1970s energy crisis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970s_energy_crisis)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "guarantee" in the [Jungle/garden](https://www.euronews.com/my-europe/2022/10/19/josep-borrell-apologises-for-controversial-garden-vs-jungle-metaphor-but-stands-his-ground).

Comment: @C.F.G indeed, international guarantees are usually more than just promises - more like a credible threat of force.

Comment: I think you know that the Yemeni Houthis (and generally Yemen after 2014) are not members of the Arab League!?

Comment: @C.F.G the question is not specifically about Yemen today or Houthis (see also my answer to the related question.)